# How to configure 'by google' link in google shopping results

Tags: ads, google-shopping-api, google-shopping, google-merchant-center

I am currently working on Comparison Shopping Service platform. All the ads have at the bottom 'by x' link which is a link to CSS platform hosting this price comparison ad. Now some of those links redirect user directly to homepage of CSS but this is not what I want.
Let's say I type in google shoes, and I click on one of the ads 'by x' link.
When user clicks 'by x' link I want him to either be redirected directly to product OR to page where he can see price comparison of all the shoes on my CSS platform.

But how I can configure this link in first place? I am strugling finding out how to configure this 'by x' link. I am following google documentation, but best I could find was how to configure link which will be used to redirect user to landing page of product https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/6324416?sjid=5347390595456989666-EU. But this is not what I want.

Anyone knows how to configure 'by x' link or has some useful links on how this can be configured?[image]